# Expand variadic template fold expression

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

```
template<typename... Ts>
using Type = std::variant<std::shared_ptr<T1>, std::shared_ptr<T2>, std::shared_ptr<Tn>>;
```

How I can do this using variadic templates and fold expressions?

I try something like this:

```
template<typename... Ts>
using Type = std::variant<((std::shared_ptr<Ts>), ...)>;`
```

but it doesn't compile.

Comment: Please don't guess your way around C++. Read a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) instead.

Comment: Always post error along with your code, always.

Comment: `template<typename... Ts>
using Type = std::variant<std::shared_ptr<Ts>...>;` ?

Comment: Don't mix variadic templates and fold expressions. They are completely different things. In your case no fold expression is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [compiled](https://godbolt.org/z/s6n3vn3vf) for me

```
template<typename... Ts>
using Type = std::variant<std::shared_ptr<Ts>...>;
```

As stated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#:%7E:text=no%20diagnostic%20required.-,Pack%20expansion,replaced%20by%20each%20of%20the%20elements%20from%20the%20pack%2C%20in%20order.,-template%3Cclass)

> A pattern followed by an ellipsis, in which the name of at least one parameter pack appears at least once, is expanded into zero or more comma-separated instantiations of the pattern, where the name of the parameter pack is replaced by each of the elements from the pack, in order

Here our pattern is `std::shared_ptr<Ts>`, which is expanded into `std::shared_ptr<T1>, std::shared_ptr<T2>, std::shared_ptr<Tn>`